# Applying clustering on variables

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Can someone please explain the logic behind varclushi. I am unable to find any documentation relating to the algorithms behind this function.

Comment: I was hoping for a mathematical solution but anyway thanks

Comment: try this community https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/jingmin1987/variable-clustering/blob/master/decomposition/var_clus.py? If so, which part do you need more information on?

Comment: This is a one-year package created in Feb 2019. Do you really expect a lot of people to know this? Why don't you rather ask the author? He'll likely be happy to help in order to promote his new package.